# Concrete class injection considered bad practice

Tags: dependency-injection, dependency-inversion

I am curious about dependency inversion principle in general, and whether it should be enforced strictly all the time.

I know that using interfaces to be injected in general promotes loose coupling, which has positive impact.

However, there are certain types of class that will most likely always have only one implementation, and likely not to change over time. I really am questioning having every objects backed by an interface, e.g. FooService, with FooServiceImpl.

I am in a dilemma because I think concrete class injection is generally frowned upon by many folks.

tl;dr 
Should dependency injection always be done with interfaces only, even when certain classes are unlikely to change, and hence, backing it by interface seems to add unwanted complexity?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, Dependency Injection start to be useful as soon as there's more than one implementation. I understand that you have only one concrete implementation but if you follow developpement bests practices you'll want to unit test every class. And if a BarService depends on your FooService, you will write a unit test BarServiceTest that rely on a  fake implementation of FooService (a mock or something like that).

In other words, as soon as you write unit test your app you end up with to implementations of your service : the real one used at runtime, the fake one used for unit testing (or a single implementation but configured differently depending on the context).

Answer (score 0):

Just couple of things.

`Dependency injection (DI)` !== `Inversion of Control (IoC)` !== `Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP)`

I can't recall better (being same brief and explanatory) reading on the topic other than [this](https://martinfowler.com/articles/dipInTheWild.html#YouMeanDependencyInversionRight)

Second aspect is language and(or) tools dependent. Certainly I can't speak of all the languages and their tools-stack available, but there *might* be some where test-doubling an interface would be a better approach than generating a double as a child class of the class being mocked.

So my personal (and subjective) answer for

> Should dependency injection always be done with interfaces only, even
>   when certain classes are unlikely to change, and hence, backing it by
>   interface seems to add unwanted complexity?

is definitely **'no'** because of unneeded complexity in classes structure. Besides, doing DI usually means some kind of dependency injection container is used to manage dependencies, which in turn means extra configuration efforts.

Personally, I introduce interfaces by intent only when I really do have such an intent explicitly. All other interfaces that appear in code are just extractions during development/refactoring process (in other words, I create such abstractions only when me or my code come to the need of those).